# How to call a class from another class in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel eloquent. I am having two tables roles, users. For that  having two classes rols and users. How can i get the data from roles table in user class. It can be possible by extending user class inside roles class?

Comment: Are you talking about [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what I think you mean is, you want to use laravel relationships. You can find a lot of info in the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships). If you're still not sure how it works after reading the docs, Jeffrey Way makes great tutorials about Laravel and the laravel [relationship episode](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14) is free ;)